# iDRAC on Dell R710 and R720

Tags: dell, drac, dell-poweredge

I've called Dell twice to try and clarify this basic (or so I thought) question, but I've had two different answers so far.

We have a Dell R710, and a Dell R720. Does DRAC come installed by default on either? Dell said it comes build into the motherboard on the R720 but the second time I rang, they said we didn't have it.

Can anyone tell me if DRAC comes as standard on the R720?

I'm aware we'll need a license as well, I'm just interested in the physical capability on the server.

I've never used DRAC before and know next to nothing about it, so apologies if this seems blindingly simple.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Express version of iDRAC 7 comes standard on the R720, with an optional upgrade for the Enterprise version](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/dell-poweredge-r720-spec-sheet.pdf).

Comment: But is that a hardware upgrade on the R720? Or will buying a license enable the Enterprise version? Also, does that mean all R720 servers WILL have a dedicated port on the back for DRAC?

Comment: @BT643 To upgrade from Express to Enterprise after the fact, you need to buy additional hardware.  They sell a riser card you can install for this purpose.  The Express version of iDRAC does not come with a dedicated NIC port, among other things.  [Check out Dell's iDRAC 7 feature guide for more details](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/extras/m/white_papers/20065812.aspx).

Comment: Right, ok. No idea why Dell were avoiding the point when I was asking them repeatedly! So if a server has an "iDRAC" port on the back, does it mean it is capable of using iDRAC Enterprise? Or is it possible there will be a port on the back for iDRAC Express also?

Comment: @BT643 A dedicated NIC port for iDRAC means iDRAC Enterprise hardware is installed, yes.  (Assuming iDRAC7, at least.)

Answer (score 3):

iDRAC 7 Express comes on R720.  To upgrade to Enterprise you purchase a licence then upload the licence to the iDRAC it is not a hardware upgrade.  You can do this when you purchase the server or after the fact.  This is a change from iDRAC 6 on the R710.